# Mechanism for a reaction of reduced fluorophenol with BF3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, halides

In the given question, $\ce{BF3}$ will act as an electrophile. Will it form $\ce{BF4-}$ and leave a positive charge on the carbocation to which $\ce F$ was attached or react with $\ce{OH}$. It will form phenol but what will be the mechanism for the reaction?

[image: 4-fluorocyclohexa-2,5-dien-1-ol + BF3]

Comment: It will react with the phenol to form a complex

Comment: In my textbook the major product formed was phenol. Can you pls provide the mechanism for the formation of phenol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boron trifluoride will indeed remove the fluoride ion to form tetrafluoborate. Fluoride removal is favored by two related factors:

1. The carbon-fluorine bond us more polarized than the carbon-oxygen bond, making the fluorine a stronger negative charge center for the partially-positive boron.
2. Because fluorine is more electron-withdrawing than hydroxyl, the carbocation is more stable and more easily formed by retaining the hydroxyl function.

The carbocation does not simply retain its positive charge in the originally fluoridated carbon. That carbon is conjugated with double bonds, and the $\ce{C-H}$ hydrogen in the $\ce{CHOH}$ group can tautomerize to form an aromatic cation (protonated phenol):

[image]

Then the fluoborate can be protonated by this cation, giving phenol, hydrogen fluoride, and regenerated boron trifluoride. The boron trifluoride is thus actually a catalyst for the thermal decomposition.

Comment: So after carbonation is formed it will rearrange and hydrogen will shift on OH to form aromatic ring thus making it more stable and the H from H2O+ will form Hydrogen fluoride after reacting with BF4-. Am I right?

Comment: I would regard the carbocation as a superposition ofcall four structures. The same proton is either the polarized C-H proton on the CHOH group or the excess proton on oxygen in the peotonated phenol structure; because that is the same proton we can't distinguish that experimentally.

Comment: Alright got it thanks a lot.